# Qt Creator not showing log messages on Android 8.0 (LG G6)

Tags: android, linux, qt, debugging, qt-creator

So I am writing an application for Android, then I tried to run in Debug mode by connecting my phone (Android 8.0) via usb, the application launches fine on the device and works fine, but in "Application Output" tab there is no log messages. When I run the application on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04), the log messages are there. Then I tried to run the app on Release on my phone and more frustratingly the log messages are still not there and my app is behaving strangely, that is it fails to make network requests (not all of them but only a few) and it doesn't load data from the internet (everything works well in debug mode).

Here is my "Kits" configuration:

[image: My "Kits" configuration]

Comment: UPDATE: I have investigated this issue further and found that this is a device specific problem. Indeed I have tested the application on a LG G6 Android 8.0 and could not get the logging system to work, when I switched to a Sony Xperia XA2 Android 8.0 the "Application Output" displays the log messages correctly. I have tried to reset the developer settings on my LG G6, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Which version of QtCreator are you using?

Comment: @Felix The version of Qt Creator is 4.7.0

Comment: I have also tried to perform a hard reset and completely erasing the device, but the log messages are still not showing up on my LG G6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrying with latest Android 9.0 Pie update on LG G6, the problem is no longer present and `adb logcat` works as expected.